# How to have the time permanently visible in Win 8.1 Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8.1, time, modern-ui, clock

How can I keep the time always on top/always visible when I'm using different apps in the Modern UI mode? Thanks!

Comment: Time provided by what application exactly?  If your talking about the clock in the task bar, that isn't possible, unless of course you have 2 monitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep your task bar clock since Metro apps completely different than the desktop behaviour. You  can however hover the mouse on the right top/bottom corners of screen to get the sidebar. Once you see the sidebar hovering your mouse over any button will show the current time.

Alternatively, you may keep your metro applications vertically by placing them on your left side. So that you can see the more metro apps and/or desktop in the same view. So you can get the desktop's task bar clock for view.

Comment: Keyboard alternate to what has been suggested is "Windows key+C". This shows all the charms and time, when using the Windows Store (Modern UI) apps.